# UISwitch/UISlider values when switching ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How would you keep the value of a UISwitch or UISlider so that when you leave and come back to the ViewController it will have the same value as you left it at?

I don't have much knowledge or experience with swift so if you can, please explain in Objective-C!

Comment: It depends, do you have to keep that value when you quit the app?

Comment: No, just for when the app is running - it can reset once the app is closed.

Comment: You need to save the value of your `UISlider` somewhere. `NSUserDefault` can be a candidate.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the switch state to NSUserDefault like this.

Add an action connected with your swich button

.h file

```
- (IBAction)changeStatus:(id)sender;
```

.m file

```
- (IBAction)changeStatus:(id)sender {
Boolean status;
UISwitch *mySwitch = (UISwitch *)sender;
if ([mySwitch isOn]) {
    status = 1;
} else {
    status = 0;
}
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:status forKey:@"switchStatus"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

}

And load for using

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
Boolean switchStatus = [defaults boolForKey:@"switchStatus"];
if (switchStatus)
{
    [_switchButton setOn:YES animated:YES];
}else{
    [_switchButton setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value in a model or - to make it easy for you - inside your AppDelegate you established the connection in a former question. Note: You should learn about MVC - this is just to keep it easy for you. A good starting point for MVC  is this answer: [Design Pattern - Objective-C - MVC Model View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971272/design-pattern-objective-c-mvc-model-view-controller)

Extend your appDelegate.h with

```
@property double sliderValue;
```

Then in your viewController.m implement

```
- (void)viewDidDissapear {
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate setSliderValue:YourSlider.value];
}
```

To load it the next time implement

```
- (void)viewWillAppear {
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [yourSlider setValue:appDelegate.sliderValue];
}
```

Don't forget to import your AppDelegate.h file in you viewCOntroller.m file.

```
#import "MyAppDelegate.h"
```